# The locus of points $z$ which satisfy $|z - k^2c| = k|z - c|$, for $k \neq 1$, is a circle

Tags: circles, analytic-geometry, locus

Use algebra to prove that the locus of points z which satisfy $|z - k^2c| = k|z - c|$, for $k \neq 1$ and $c = a + bi$ any fixed complex number, is a circle centre $O$.
Give the radius of the circle in terms of $k$ and $|c|$.

I squared both sides and got this:
 $$(k^2−1)x^2+(k^2−1)y^2+(a^2+b^2-k^2a^2-k^2b^2)k^2=0$$

I might have gone wrong somewhere though.

Edit. Never mind, I didn't go wrong.

$$(k^2-1)x^2+(k^2-1)y^2-(k^2-1)k^2a^2-(k^2-1)k^2b^2=0$$
$$x^2+y^2=k^2(a^2+b^2)$$
$$r^2=k^2(a^2+b^2)$$
$$r=k|c|$$

Comment: First, as a general rule, don't substitute in for $z$ or $c$ until you have to, your calculations will be simpler.  Second, use the fact that if $w$ iw a complex number, $|w|^2=w\cdot \overline{w}$.  That will square it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps
$$ \left|z - k^2c\right| = k\left|z - c\right| $$
$$ \left|z - k^2c\right|^2 = k^2\left|z - c\right|^2 $$
$$ \left(z - k^2c\right)\left(\overline{z - k^2c}\right) = k^2(z - c)\left(\overline{z-c}\right) $$
$$ \left(z - k^2c\right)\left(\overline{z} - k^2\overline{c}\right) = k^2(z - c)\left(\overline{z}-\overline{c}\right) $$
$$ \left|z\right|^2 - k^2\overline{c}z-k^2c\overline{z}+k^4\left|c\right|^2= k^2\left(\left|z\right|^2-\overline{c}z-c\overline{z} + \left|c\right|^2\right) $$
$$ \left|z\right|^2 - k^2\overline{c}z-k^2c\overline{z}+k^4\left|c\right|^2= k^2\left|z\right|^2-k^2\overline{c}z-k^2c\overline{z} + k^2\left|c\right|^2 $$
$$ \left|z\right|^2 -k^2c\overline{z}+k^4\left|c\right|^2= k^2\left|z\right|^2-k^2c\overline{z} + k^2\left|c\right|^2 $$
$$ \left|z\right|^2 +k^4\left|c\right|^2= k^2\left|z\right|^2 + k^2\left|c\right|^2 $$
$$ \left|z\right|^2 -k^2\left|z\right|^2= k^2\left|c\right|^2 -k^4\left|c\right|^2$$
$$ \left|z\right|^2\left(1 -k^2\right)= k^2\left|c\right|^2\left(1 -k^2\right)$$
$$ \left|z\right|^2= k^2\left|c\right|^2$$
$$ \left|z\right|= k\left|c\right|$$

Comment: The second line does not follow from the first line: for a complex number, $|w|^2=w\cdot \overline w$, not $|w|^2=w^2.

Comment: @Aaron, please see my edit. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, everything looks correct now.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If you square both sides, and expand out (initially writing things in terms of your variables and their complex conjugates), you will get a lot of useful cancellation.

Here is the beginning of such a calculation, to help you out.

Squaring the left hand side yields:

$$(z-k^2c)(\overline{z}-k^2\overline{c})=|z|^2+k^4|c|^2-k^2(z\overline{c}+\overline{z}c).$$

Similarly, squaring the right hand side yields:

$$k^2(|z|^2+|c|^2-(z\overline{c}+\overline{z}c)).$$

Setting the two sides equal and rearranging, we have

$$(k^2-1)|z|^2=(k^4-k^2)|c|^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

instead of squaring let me see if conjugates help.

$\begin{eqnarray}
0 = |z - k^2c|^2 -k^2 |z -c|^2 &=& (z - k^2 c)(\bar z - k^2 \bar c) -k^2(z-c)(\bar z - \bar c) \\
&=& z \bar z - k^2 c \bar z - k^2\bar c z + k^4 c \bar c -k^2(z \bar z - c \bar z -z  \bar c + c \bar c)  )\\
&=&(1-k^2)z \bar z - k^2(1-k^2)c\bar c \\
&=&(1-k^2)(|z|^2 - k^2|c|^2)
\end{eqnarray}$

$ \mbox{ if } k^2 \neq 1, \mbox{ then } |z|^2 = k^2|c|^2$